# How to add SSl certificate to Kestrel in .Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, kestrel-http-server

I have a valid SSL certificate with a base64 format key. I have added the certificate using Nginx. but not working. routing is still hitting HTTP, not hitting HTTPS.network team suggest me to add a certificate directly to kestrel.

appsettings.json

```
 "Kestrel": {
    "https_port": 443,
    "EndPoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://*:7003"
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to your `appsettings.json`:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://*:7003",
      "Certificate": {
        "Path": "path-to-your-pfx-file.pfx",
        "Password": "password"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configureiconfiguration) and the ASP.NET Core [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a78322dc7e9c81bac3aa79c63482a13e7425935a/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/ConfigurationReader.cs#L69) that loads the config.

Comment: I did already. but still not redirecting.

Comment: Are you looking to just start your server on HTTPS or adding [automatic redirect to HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#require-https)?

Comment: Yes, I am looking to start my server redirecting to HTTPS.I did all steps mentioned in the link. but still showing the site is not secure.